# Disallow anything but GET for certain links in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-post

I have a simple blog webpage with a lot of links. They are all using `GetMapping`. Therefore whenever I have a bot try to access those pages using POST I get an error saying

`Request method 'Post' not supported.`

I understand that this is caused because I use `@GetMapping`, and if I switch to `@RequestMapping` then everything will be fine. However I do not want to allow anyone to access my blog with POST. The only page that should be POST is `/contact/message` except that page everything should be accessed through GET.

So I have two questions:
How do I enforce people to use GET only.
How do I catch attempts to use POST and redirect them to `/error`?

Sidenote: I do not use spring security, there is no logging in or anything that is hidden behind an account. Also most of my mappings are using regex. Do not know if this info is of any help or not.

```
@GetMapping(value = {
            "", "{page:^[1-9][0-9]*$}", "{section:^\\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[^.]+$}",
            "{section:^\\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[^.]+$}/{page:^[1-9][0-9]*$}"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter in your application:

```
public class Tfil implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                         ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if (!"GET".equals(req.getMethod())) {
            //redirect or error page
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            //here redirect
            res.sendRedirect("redirect url");
            //or return 404 code
            res.setStatus(404);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
    }
}
```